# Write text messages using Vim

Tags: sms

I have an Android phone (Motorola XT 1068 Moto G) that I use mostly for sending text messages.

Being a heavy Vim user, I'm frustrated with the low speed of writing messages using the Android keyboard.

Is there some way I can use Vim to write text messages on the phone?

Answer (score 2):

## With AirDroid + withExEditor

First, you establish a connection between a laptop or desktop computer with a proper keyboard and the Android phone.

On the phone, install the [AirDroid app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en_US).

On the laptop, use the [web application](https://web.airdroid.com/) to connect to your phone. Currently (2018-06-21), this requires a free registration.

Using "Messages" in the web application (see screenshot below) you'll be able to write text messages on your laptop, sending them via your phone.

[image: Messages in AirDroid web app]

To write those messsages conveniently using Vim, you can use the [withExEditor](https://github.com/asamuzaK/withExEditor) add-on for Firefox and Chrome.

After installling the add-on, and doing [some additional setup](https://github.com/asamuzaK/withExEditorHost#user-content-host-setup) on your laptop, you can use gVim to write your text messages.